# Pythonic way to take the only item from a list

Tags: python

Sometimes a function returns a list, but you know it has only one item. One way to get it is

```
a = somefunc()[0]
```

If the list has more than one item, they will be silently discarded.

[This article](http://blog.ram.rachum.com/post/1198230058/python-idiom-for-taking-the-single-item-from-a) suggests using

```
(a,) = somefunc()
```

A comment proposes just

```
a, = somefunc()
```

Both have the advantage that an array with more than one element gives a `ValueError: too many values to unpack`. They also work with tuples, sets, and other collections.

Are those methods considered Pythonic or confusing? Do they have any drawbacks?

Comment: The `(a,)` form seems most readable/functional to me. It produces `ValueError` and is more readable, especially while skimming, than the form without parens.

Comment: Dealing with the tuple notation (a,) is what I and older Python devs use.

Comment: When would you want to entice an error to occur and not store the extra information? If you use any of these methods, all the extra info is lost. Surely you want it for debugging purposes if it is there.

Comment: That might be nice when only taking the 0th element but what if you need the 4th? You end up with `_,_,_,_a = somefunc()` instead of `a = somefunc()[4]`.

Comment: you could also do `somefunc().pop()`.

Comment: @IanAuld "...you know it has only one item".

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan The use case is for something like a database cursor. Consider `cursor.execute("select 1").fetchone()`. You know, from the SQL statement, that the return value of `fetchone` will have length 1.

Comment: It seems unlikely to me that most developers would write a method/function that returns only one value and then just for the heck of it wraps it in a list. So I would say the far more likely scenario is only needing one value from a returned list of values.

Comment: @IanAuld See my comment above.

Comment: My comment still stands. It far more likely, not a certainty however as your example demonstrates, you will get a list with multiple values. In most cases a function/method that returns a list _could_ have more than one value.

Comment: It may be that the function can return more than one value, but the way I am using it should only return one. If the list contains more than one value, then something has gone wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've always taken preference in

```
(a,) = somefunc()
```

for exactly the reasons pointed out in the article. It assumes only 1 element in the list. It is easier to read. And it makes the assertion for you.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Python3 a good method is to unpack the remaining values into a variable that can be accessed or not.  This avoids raising a ValueError in the chance that more than one value is returned.

```
>>> a, *b = ['this', 'that', 'other']
>>> a
'this'
>>> b
['that', 'other']
```

Comment: This seems especially useful for allowing you to see what unwanted values got returned.

Comment: Good answer! If they're only looking for the 1 I'd use something like: try: (a,) = somefunc() catch: a, *b = somefunc() and log b so you're not carrying b around for no reason but you get the goodness of seeing what was stored in it if extra elements were present. PS sorry for terrible formatting, ctrl + k is a no go in comments.

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 But that means you have to rerun the function, and there is the possibility that you get a different result the second time, with only the one parameter.

Comment: @Obj3ctiv3_C_88 You could `a, *b = sumfunc()` and check `if b: log b` which allows you to run the function only once to avoid potentially getting a different result.

Comment: @SteveO'Driscoll Both are good and it'd really depend on what sumfunc() is returning. It'd also depend on how often you anticipate running into the exception. If most of the time you expect a passing case I'd stick with try: catch: since its around 60% faster in passing cases